# Python Variable Scope, variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, scope

I am testing a very simple python script. What the function does is not important to my question, my question is the following code somehow gives me:

```
File "test.py", line 13, in traverse
    if root.val > minVal and ans > root.val:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ans' referenced before assignment
```

But I do have `ans` defined, why does it not complain about `minVal` but does about `ans`?

```
class Test(object):

    def findSecondMinimumValue(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: int
        """
        minVal = root.val
        ans = float("inf")

        def traverse(root):
            if not root:
                return

            if root.val > minVal and ans > root.val:
                ans = root.val

            traverse(root.left)
            traverse(root.right)

        traverse(root)
        return ans if ans != float("inf") else -1
```

Comment: You assign to `ans = ...` as a result, Python sees `ans ` in the `traverse` function as local. Note that this assignment has no use here, since you only set a reference.

Comment: Ah, how dump am I, thanks for your answer, I got it now!

Answer (score 1):

Inside your function `traverse` you are defining a new variable ans, which has nothing to do with the ans you defined above. if you want to use the same variable put `nonlocal ans` at the top of your `traverse` function.

Comment: I got it now, thank you!